# How to compile the example code from libcouchbase

Tags: c, couchbase, libcouchbase

I was trying to install the Couchbase Server and libcouchbase (C SDK), when I followed the steps from the official website to compile the example code minimal.c, It shows a lot of errors that I can't eliminate.

Here are the environment informations:

System: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Couchbase Server: Couchbase Server 6.0.0 Community

C SDK: libouchbase 2.10

when I compile the example code minimal.c with:
$ gcc -lcouchbase -o minimal minimal.c

Then it shows errors:

/tmp/ccfC5RfB.o：In function‘die(lcb_st*, char const*, lcb_STATUS)’：

minimal.c:(.text+0x20)：undefined reference to ‘lcb_strerror’

/tmp/ccfC5RfB.o：In function‘store_callback(lcb_st*, int, lcb_RESPSTORE_ const*)’：

minimal.c:(.text+0x7e)：undefined reference to ‘lcb_respstore_status’

minimal.c:(.text+0x8b)：undefined reference to ‘lcb_strcbtype’

minimal.c:(.text+0xc4)：undefined reference to ‘lcb_respstore_key’

minimal.c:(.text+0xff)：undefined reference to ‘lcb_respstore_cas’

minimal.c:(.text+0x128)：undefined reference to ‘lcb_strcbtype’

...

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: After Reinstallation of the system, the problem was solved